# DataMapper, Rails 3.1 How do I skip migrations on a repository a Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

I've been searching quite a bit (and experimenting with monkey patching) for a solution to this issue but no avail.

I am wondering ... how do I prevent migrations from executing on a class that has DataMapper::Resource included in it?

In my Rails app, I have a few classes that connect to a different repository than the default. So they are essentially read only. I want to exclude them from the auto_migrations that happen with rake tasks. This way I can rest assured I won't be triggering any bad behavior on a database I shouldn't be trying to migrate. (user permissions err out properly so this is more about proper form IMO, the databases around here are maintained by DBAs)

This behavior would be only on a few models that utilize a repository separate from the default repo. So I still need migrations for the classes using the default repo.

I having a feeling this is probably much easier than I am finding it to be but I am throwing it out to the DM community.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly solution?

```
klass = ToProtect
noop = proc {|*|}
DataMapper::Migrations::Model.instance_methods.each do |meth|
  klass.define_method(meth, &noop)
end
```